# how to aggregate and group by on multiple tables in postgresql in pandas

Tags: sql, postgresql

I having some trouble with group by in postgresql. I am not a whiz and just about get by.

I have joined 3 tables together using ids in each. there is some aggregated data also. What i want to do is then group by region however i get repeated rows of region rather than it being grouped together.

Meta table

```
 -------------------------------
 |id    | Region   | Area      |
 -------------------------------
 |876   | London   | Ruislip   |
 -------------------------------
 | 899  |South West| Cheltenham|
 -------------------------------
```

T1 table

```
  -----------------------
 |id    | Total_spend   | 
 ------------------------
 |876   | 89999         |
 ------------------------
 | 899  | 76664         |
 ------------------------
```

T2 table

```
  --------------------------
 |id    | Total_expend     | 
 ---------------------------
 |876   | 8999             |
 ---------------------------
 | 899  | 7837             |
 ---------------------------
 |876   | 89999            |
 ---------------------------
 | 899  | 6777             |
```

The following code is as follows

```
 Select meta.region, T1.total_spend,
              Sum(T2.total_expend),
 from meta,t1,t2
 where meta.id = T1.id and meta.id=T2.id
 Group by meta.region, T1.total_spend
```

i get repeating rows in the region column because there are several of the same rows in T2 but not even sure its aggregating correctly.

I am not sure how to work this one out.

Desired output

```
 ----------------------------------------
 | Region   | total_spend | total_expend|
 ----------------------------------------
 | London   | 89999       | 90898       |
 ----------------------------------------
 |South West| 76664       | 14614       |
 ----------------------------------------
```

So total_expend is aggregated by sum T1 and T2 connect's to meta via id and i want to then group by region on meta table if its possible

Comment: Why is this tagged as pandas.  I see no use of pandas whatsoever.

Comment: Can you post a desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to group by the `region`.

```
SELECT meta.region,
       sum(t1.total_spend),
       sum(t2.total_expend)
       FROM meta
            INNER JOIN t1
                       ON meta.id = t1.id
            INNER JOIN t2
                       ON meta.id = t2.id
       GROUP BY meta.region;
```

If you additionally `GROUP BY t1.total_spend` you'll split each group for a `region` in subgroups per `total_spend`.

Also consider using explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than commas in the `FROM`. It's easier to read and understand.